# KNN Modeling Python

Tags: python, knn

Apparently the dataset contains NaN and so the KNeighborsClassifier isn't working.
This is my dataset I'm using: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/thehapyone/uci-online-news-popularity-data-set

This is the full code I'm running taken from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/code/thehapyone/exploratory-analysis-for-online-news-popularity

This is the part that is having problems (it is line 75 from the full code in the link above):

```
# defining the model
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

k_range = np.arange(1,100)
accuracy = []

for n in k_range:
    neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=n, n_jobs=-1)
    neigh.fit(X_train_2, y_train_2)

    # predict the result
    y_pred = neigh.predict(X_test_2)

    #print ("Random Forest Classifer Result")
    #print ("Performance - " + str(100*accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test_2)) + "%")
    accuracy.append(100*accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test_2))
```

This is the error I'm getting:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 7>()
10
11     # predict the result
**---> 12     y_pred = neigh.predict(X_test_2)**
13
14     #print ("Random Forest Classifer Result")

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan, msg_dtype, estimator_name, input_name)
159                 "#estimators-that-handle-nan-values"
160             )
--> 161         raise ValueError(msg_err)
162
163

**ValueError: Input X contains NaN.**
KNeighborsClassifier does not accept missing values encoded as NaN natively. For supervised learning, you might want to consider sklearn.ensemble.HistGradientBoostingClassifier and Regressor which accept missing values encoded as NaNs natively. Alternatively, it is possible to preprocess the data, for instance by using an imputer transformer in a pipeline or drop samples with missing values. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html You can find a list of all estimators that handle NaN values at the following page: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html#estimators-that-handle-nan-values

---

Answer (score 0):

your data contains NaN(some blocks which has no values), this can disturb the ML. With:

```
df = pd.csv("some data")
de = df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

you can clean your data but with the command you eliminate also the rows which contains NaN. If its border you then use the command fillna(), it can replace the NaN with a (for example) string, integer, what ever you want.